# Resize PhotoImage using .zoom or .subsample

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I want to resize PhotoImage at load stage. As you know, `.zoom` and `.subsample` cannot work with floating variables, only integers. Now I resize it with wrong way:

```
i1=PhotoImage(file="res\\1h.gif").zoom(new_size).subsample(old_size)
```

It works with small pictures but now I tried medium picture, and got error:

> self.tk.call(destImage, 'copy', self.name, '-zoom',x,y)
>
> _tkinter.TclError: not enough free memory for image buffer

Comment: maybe use `PIL` to resize it and convert to `tkinter.PhotoImage` using `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy, if u want resize an PhotoImage, u can use 2 methods :

- .zoom(number) : return bigger image >> with {number} times bigger
- or .subsample(number) : return smaller image >> with {number} times smaller